# Assign several simple products at once

Tags: import

I'm using https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport extension to create new simple products programmatically and then assign them to existing configurable product. Problem is I can assign single SKU but can't assign several at once with error "Product with specified super products SKU not found"

```
<?php

// Trying to assign several simples at once
// either $simples as comma-separated SKU or an array() doesn't work

$assignProducts[] = array(
    'sku' => $configurableProduct->getSku(),
    '_type' => '',
    '_attribute_set' => '',
    '_super_products_sku' => $simples
);
```

Is the only way to do it is to pass each SKU separately to Mage::getSingleton('fastsimpleimport/import')->processProductImport()?

Anyone faced this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$simples` is an array that's not going to work, you'd need to create several rows:

```
$assignProducts[] = array(
    'sku' => $configurableProduct->getSku(),
    '_type' => '',
    '_attribute_set' => '',
    '_super_products_sku' => 'sku1'
);
$assignProducts[] = array(
    '_super_products_sku' => 'sku2'
);
```

There was an issue about this exact same problem yesterday, please have a look at: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/9

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks again :) I looked at the export csv format, but didn't figure how to do it without specifying the required attributes